# Laravel 5.8 Posting Likes with AJAX call gives me Internal Server Error 500

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to implement a likes system for my Laravel web app. It is a recipe application. To build the likes system, I'm using AJAX (my previous likes system was simply through Laravel using Many-to-Many but this required page load for every like). The issue I am getting is an Internal Server Error 500 whenever I hit the like button, and I don't know why. I've been messing with it for hours and can't get anything out of it.

**AJAX**

```
// Likes AJAX
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

var recipeId = 0;

$('.like').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    recipeId = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.dataset['recipeId'];
    var isLike = event.target.previousElementSibling == null;

$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: urlLike,
    data: {isLike: isLike, recipeId: recipeId},
    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}
})
.done(function(){
    event.target.innerText = isLike ? event.target.innerText == 'Like' ? 'You like this' : 'Like':
    event.target.innerText == 'Unlike' ? 'You like this' : 'Unlike';

    if(isLike){
        event.taget.innerText = 'Unlike';
    } else {
        event.taget.innerText = 'Like';
    }
});
});
```

**Blade/View**

```php
{{-- Likes --}}
@if (Auth::check())
    <div>
        <button class="like" data-recipeId="{{$recipe->id}}">Like!</button>
        <span id="likes-count-{{$recipe->id}}"></span>
    </div>
@else
    <div>
        <a href="{{route('login')}}">
            <button>Like It!</button>
        </a>
        <a href="{{route('login')}}">
            <button>Unlike It!</button>
        </a>
    </div>
@endif
```

The following are included in my layouts file.

```
<script>
    var urlLike = '{{ route('like') }}'
</script>  
<script src="/js/custom.js"></script>
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Does anyone know where I should begin to search for the error and how I should go about correcting it? If you need any more code, such as my controllers or models, please let me know.

Comment: try logging your error stacktrace with: `error: function(e, r, o) {
console.log(e,r, o);
}`

Comment: Thank you I ran a stacktrace and found where the error was. It was a minor issue in my routes. However, it seems as though it is not posting to my DB table. There is no error in the console anymore, but it won't post. Any ideas? @MalkhaziDartsmelidze